# Why can you choose which technology you would like to work with and also not prefer not to work with it?

Tags: discussion, bug, developer-story

I was testing the developer-story feature and noticed something I consider to be a bug. Not really sure if it is but that doesn't look right to me.

Any tag that is added to  *"Tech you want to work with"* can also be added to *"Tech you prefer not to work with"*.
[image]

Shouldn't it be impossible to select the-same tag/technology if it is already in one these options?

I don't think a person would want to work with one technology and at the-same time, does not want to work with that same exact technology.

Comment: A love hate relationship maybe?

Comment: I think it is important for employers to know what technologies you are not experienced with or cannot work with before hiring you. Love hate relationship won't be helpful in that case.

Comment: Experience and preference are separate issues. Experience can already be gleaned in the tag percentiles. You can be really good with Java but still hate working with it.

Comment: @BoltClock This isn't selecting experience though. It's saying they want to work with it.

Comment: @Rob: Exactly. So I don't know what Programmer is going on about in their comment to Memor-X.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, sorry - didn't realise your comment was a reply - I thought it was a general comment on the post

Comment: @BoltClock I believe if you are experienced with some technology you would want to work with it. Maybe I am wrong. Forget about that comment. The one in my question is what I really want to know.

Comment: Is there some kind of double negation going on in the question title here?

Comment: I don't think so but if you have a better title you can always edit it.

Comment: Well the *"not prefer not to work with it"* bit threw me off but if it's supposed to read like that I won't edit it just because I'm confused. Figured I'd ask though.

Comment: @ivarni no you're right, it is a double negation. It should be "prefer not to work with it". That's the exact text in the page after all.

Comment: Do we really need to write code that prevents people from doing nonsensical things? Just don't indicate that you simultaneously do and don't want to work with a technology.

Comment: @CodyGray *"Do we really need to write code that prevents people from doing nonsensical things?"* Yes, just like you can't let people add multiple tags in questions. I guess that code/feature is pretty much useless too.... Well, not to me. I think that the tag should not appear if it has already appeared in one of those options. People will always do stupid stupid stuff. Sometimes, it can be an actual mistake. You prevent that mistake by making that impossible to do like the question feature.

Comment: *"Yes, just like you can't let people add multiple tags in questions"* What? Of course you can add multiple tags to questions.

Comment: Was just tired when I made that comment. Meant to "the-same tag multiple times". You can't add the-same tag multiple times in a question and I guarantee you that writing that code prevents people from such doing nonsensical things such as that. Otherwise, you would see thousands of questions with the-same tag multiple times.